# Pyside Drag and Drop from one ListView to another

Tags: python, pyside2

I am trying to dive into QlistView and Models and therefore explicitly used those above QListWidgets. But I do have problems to make Drag and Drop from one to another possible. More precisely, so far I haven't been able to catch any of the events.

I have to simple lists. One of them shows the items as expected. But once I am dragging items onto the other list, the application closes. 
At the moment I do just have simple data, but these might get more complex once I would have figured out the Interface.

A simplified and stripped-down version:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QStringListModel


class ListView(QtWidgets.QListView):

    def __init__(self, items=[], parent=None):
        super(ListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.setMaximumWidth(250)
        model = ListModel(items)
        self.setModel(model)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        super(ListView, self).dragEnterEvent(event)
        print event

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        super(ListView, self).dragLeaveEvent(event)
        print event

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(ListView, self).dragMoveEvent(event)
        print event

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        super(ListView, self).dropEvent(event)
        print event


class ListModel(QStringListModel):
    def __init__(self, items, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.items = items or []

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.items[index.row()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.items)


class View(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(View, self).__init__()
        self.list_one = ListView(["Peter", "Bjoern", "John"], parent=self)
        self.list_two = ListView(parent=self)
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.list_one)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.list_two)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = View()
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you need to set the QMimeData text so it gets passed along, and then at the `dropEvent` set the new list model.

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
    if not event.mimeData().hasText():
        event.mimeData().setText(self.currentIndex().data())
    event.accept()

def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasText():
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

def dropEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasText():
        items = self.model().items + [event.mimeData().text()]
        self.setModel(ListModel(items))
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It seems inefficient to have to create a model every time an item is dropped. I do not think it is correct.

Comment: Surely it isn't necessary, I was just showing how to get the drag/drop to work.

Comment: does anybody still have the complete code? I tried this and it segfaults on both PySide2 and PySide6